# Crash on shutdown when using second monitor

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, shutdown

I have recently added a second monitor to my setup. Instead of one VGA monitor, I now have one VGA and one DVI monitor hooked up to the computer. The displays work just fine. However, ever since this monitor was added Ubuntu (10.10) does not shut down properly. I go to shutdown and it starts shutting down but just hangs and I need to manually shut it down. This has been like this for weeks and I feel not comfortable shutting it down this way over and over again.

Has anybody any idea what this can be? Or, also useful, does anybody know how to get some info on why this crash occurs? Any logs that can be used for this?

Thanks!

Paul

Comment: You might want to check syslog and kern.log in /var/log/ for error messages.  Also, you should consider removing the second monitor temporarily to verify that's the root cause.  It might just be a coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to fix the problem. Apparently with the dual monitor setup the boot screen itself caused the crash it seems. The only thing I did was turn off the splash screens in grub, and it now finally works well!

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding `acpi=force` to grub using `grub-customizer`, and running `sudo update-grub`, solved the issue.

Comment: Can you provide more information about how to use `grub-customizer`?